# Graphing RGB Values of Pictures with matplotlob

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, rgb

(Update)
A lot of people saw this. I want to apologise first off, this is my first time asking on SO. Didn't mean to cause any confusion. So what I'm trying to do is, instead of getting a graph where the RGB values are lined up on a singular line, I want to have the values spread out onto the 3d plane. It's a bit hard for me to describe. I'll post an image of a different graph produced by my code and something that resembles what I would prefer.

The graph produced based on another image that was used as input. Please note how it is scattered on the z axis, but not the x and y

[image]

An example of what I would like my graph to generally resemble. Points are scattered through the space. (Not my program, will link to original code)

[image]

[mplot3d tutorial - source for example graph](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)

Sorry for pestering. Worked on a small assignment for comp. sci. class where the program intakes a user's image and then displays it on a 3D graph. The program works, and the graph presents, but I had to alter the way the graph looks because of array's pickiness for being the same shape. Here's what the graph of a test image looks like:

[image: Graph produced by program. Note how the lines are straight one dimensional lines instead of being more 2d and spread out.]

Don't get me wrong, I do have a general idea of how to fix this, but I've been pseudo-coding my butt off to try to figure it out.

Anyways, here's my code. the *finfot* module serves as the image info gatherer and is the second piece of code.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import finfot3


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

b_val = finfot3.bluev
r_val = finfot3.redv
g_val = finfot3.greenv2
widthv = (finfot3.IM_Wid)**2

zv2array = np.array(g_val)
zvarray = np.array(r_val)
zv3array = np.array(b_val)
widtharray = np.array(range(widthv))

X = widtharray
Y = widtharray
Z = zvarray

X2 = widtharray
Y2 = widtharray
Z2 = zv2array

X3 = widtharray
Y3 = widtharray
Z3 = zv3array

ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, c="r", s=1)
ax.scatter(X2, Y2, Z2, c="g", s=1)
ax.scatter(X3, Y3, Z3, c="b", s=1)

ax.set_xlabel('pixel #')
ax.set_ylabel('pixel #')
ax.set_zlabel('Value of pixel w/ color')

plt.show()
```

-----------------------------------finfot file-----------------------------

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

user_inp = input("Please type in the title of your image file with the correct extension. i.e. jpg., png. Make sure image file is sqaure and is in same folder as program files.")
im = Image.open(user_inp)
pix_val_array = []
pvflat = []
for y in range(im.size[1]):
    for x in range(im.size[0]):
        pix_val_array.append((im.getpixel((x, y))))

for y in pix_val_array:
    for z in y:
        pvflat.append(z)

pvflat2 = pvflat[1:]
pvflat3 = pvflat[2:]

redv = pvflat[::3]
greenv2 = pvflat2[::3]
bluev = pvflat3[::3]


IM_Wid = im.size[0]

print(IM_Wid**2)
print(len(redv))
print(len(greenv2))
print(len(bluev))
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to get help for. Please add more details on what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you wanting 3 contours where the height of each contour is one of the RGB values and the `xy` position is the pixel position? Or am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: @WilliamMiller yes! That is exactly what I want, thank you. Like i said, I have some ideas on how to approach this, but I don't want to embarrass myself and really mess up my code